# SDK2: drag and drop between two grids

Tags: rally

Using SDK2, I've got two grids that are sorted by rank, so you can re-rank by dragging and dropping in each grid.

I would also like to drag and drop between the two grids-- imagine two team backlogs and you want to take a ranked story from one team and rank it in another team's backlog.

This seems like it would be common so is there a good example of how to do this with a Rally Grid?

I'm starting to read the following:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/drag_and_drop

But there always seem to be a few gotcha's, and for example I'm not sure how to not break the current drag drop within the grid.

Answer (score 0):

SDK 2.0rc1 is built on Ext 4.1.1a- the drag and drop functionality should be similar though.  You should be able to do this in an app as long as both the grids are in the same app.  This is a limitation due to the fact that apps run in an iframe in Rally and you can't drag and drop across the iframe boundary.

All you should need to do is pass [enableRanking](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.grid.Grid-cfg-enableRanking) true at construction of your grid.  You also will probably need to include Rank in your fetch.

Comment: This only seems to enable ranking within the grid itself-- when I define two grids right next to each other in the same app, I cannot drag from one grid to the other.  What do I need to do to enable that?

Comment: Does not help-- seems like drag and drop between two grids even in the same app is broken...